# problem installing postgresql (opengeo) on fedora 22

Tags: fedora, yum, postgresql

I'm following the directions found at `http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/installation/redhat/install.html`

i created `gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/OpenGeo.repo` with the following text:

```
[opengeo]
name=opengeo
baseurl=http://yum.opengeo.org/suite/v4/fedora/$releasever/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

when i type `yum search opengeo`

i get

```
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'opengeo' from 'http://yum.opengeo.org/suite/v4/fedora/22/x86_64': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried, disabling.
```

I understand that I'm using an out of date repository- how can I find the right one? what's the best way to install postgresql+pgadmin3 over fedora?

thanks.

Comment: also I can't add tag `dnf` because i don't have enough reputation points, but i believe it should be added